# C++ help with STL - sort() function

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, stl

Another small question about STL:

i have Dictionary:

```
map <string,vector <Wordy> > Dictionary;
```

using structure Wordy:

```
struct Wordy{ int count; string word;}
```

also this structure have overloaded operator<

```
bool operator< (Wordy& One, Wordy& Two){return One.count<Two.count;}
```

but this sort() function from algorithm doesn't work!

```
sort(Dictionary.find(s)->second.begin(),Dictionary.find(s)->second.end());
```

Comment: @Martin: The OP isn't sorting the map, she's sorting a particular *element* of the map.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your `operator<` should take its parameters by reference-to-const, I think that might be it:

```
bool operator< (const Wordy& One, const Wordy& Two){return One.count<Two.count;}
//              ^^^^^             ^^^^^
```

Answer (score 0):

check the post [How to use std::sort with a vector of structures and compare function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/328955/how-to-use-stdsort-with-a-vector-of-structures-and-compare-function) . it explains how to use sort with a customized predicate function

Comment: I don't think that's it. That question deals with a sort function that wasn't returning bool.

Comment: Why should you need a custom predicate, if you can (and want) to implement `operator<`?

Comment: @zdan: do you mean the `bool operator<(...)` function?

Comment: @NirMH: Yes, I meant the sort "predicate" not the sort function.