# How to sort vector of pointer-to-struct

Tags: c++, sorting, struct

I'm trying to sort a concurrent_vector type, where `hits_object` is:

```
struct hits_object{
        unsigned long int hash;
        int position;
};
```

Here is the code I'm using:

```
concurrent_vector<hits_object*> hits;

for(i=0;...){
    hits_object *obj=(hits_object*)malloc(sizeof(hits_object));
    obj->position=i;
    obj->hash=_prevHash[tid];
    hits[i]=obj;
}
```

Now I have filled up a `concurrent_vector<hits_object*>` called `hits`.

But I want to sort this concurrent_vector on position property!!!

Here is an example of what's inside a typical hits object:

```
0 1106579628979812621
4237 1978650773053442200
512 3993899825106178560
4749 739461489314544830
1024 1629056397321528633
5261 593672691728388007
1536 5320457688954994196
5773 9017584181485751685
2048 4321435111178287982
6285 7119721556722067586
2560 7464213275487369093
6797 5363778283295017380
3072 255404511111217936
7309 5944699400741478979
3584 1069999863423687408
7821 3050974832468442286
4096 5230358938835592022
8333 5235649807131532071
```

I want to sort this based on the first column ("position" of type `int`). The second column is "hash" of type `unsigned long int`.

Now I've tried to do the following:

`std::sort(hits.begin(),hits.end(),compareByPosition);`

where `compareByPosition` is defined as:

```
int compareByPosition(const void *elem1,const void *elem2 )
{
  return ((hits_object*)elem1)->position > ((hits_object*)elem2)->position? 1 : -1;
}
```

but I keep getting segmentation faults when I put in the line `std::sort(hits.begin(),hits.end(),compareByPosition);`

Please help!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/328955/how-to-use-stdsort-with-a-vector-of-structures-and-compare-function

Comment: 1/ Are you sure you really need to store pointers? According to the code you gave us, I'd say that storing values would probably be easier and less error-prone. If you really want to store pointers, you could have a look at the [Boost Pointer Container Library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/ptr_container/doc/ptr_container.html), or at [`boost::indirect_iterator`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/iterator/doc/indirect_iterator.html). 2/ You should not use `malloc` to create your instances, use `new` instead: `malloc` will not construct the object, just allocate...

Comment: ... some memory. 3/ To add elements in your container, you should probably use `push_back` or some similar method, unless the container is already filled. The `[]` operator is used to access elements that are already in the container, not to add new ones. The code you gave write data at some point in memory that was not reserved (well, assuming that `concurrent_vector` is similar to `std::vector` and the likes).

Comment: @LucTouraille Many thanks for that useful insight, Eamorr

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your compare function needs to return a boolean 0 or 1, not an integer 1 or -1, and it should have a strongly-typed signature:

```
bool compareByPosition(const hits_object *elem1, const hits_object *elem2 )
{
    return elem1->position < elem2->position;
}
```

The error you were seeing are due to `std::sort` interpreting everything non-zero returned from the comp function as `true`, meaning that the left-hand side is less than the right-hand side.

**NOTE** : This answer has been heavily edited as the result of conversations with sbi and Mike Seymour.

Comment: Actually, it worked perfectly for me! It's sorted my data on position

Comment: @MikeSeymour This comes straight from the [sort example](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/sort/) on cplusplus.com. I didn't think it is confusing at all: in a way (though not exactly), it is similar to passing pointers instead of iterators to STL's algorithms.

Comment: @sbi Oh, I didn't even pay attention to the OP's passing `void*` as parameters! Of course you are right, it does look confusing. I edited the answer to address this. Thanks!

Comment: @MikeSeymour You are right, I copy/pasted the OP's code, and did not look at the signature, assuming that it must be right since the compiler does not complain. I edited the answer to give the comparator a more appropriate signature.

Comment: @sbi I edited the answer again to clean it up of the confusing parts. Thanks again for spotting this.

Answer (score 5):

Without knowing what `concurrent_vector` is, I can't be sure what's causing the segmentation fault. Assuming it's similar to `std::vector`, you need to populate it with `hits.push_back(obj)` rather than `hits[i] = j`; you cannot use `[]` to access elements beyond the end of a vector, or to access an empty vector at all.

The comparison function should be equivalent to `a < b`, returning a boolean value; it's not a C-style comparison function returning negative, positive, or zero. Also, since `sort` is a template, there's no need for C-style `void *` arguments; everything is strongly typed:

```
bool compareByPosition(hits_object const * elem1, hits_object const * elem2) {
    return elem1->position < elem2->position;
}
```

Also, you usually don't want to use `new` (and certainly never `malloc`) to create objects to store in a vector; the simplest and safest container would be `vector<hits_object>` (and a comparator that takes references, rather than pointers, as arguments). If you really must store pointers (because the objects are expensive to copy and not movable, or because you need polymorphism - neither of which apply to your example), either use smart pointers such as `std::unique_ptr`, or make sure you `delete` them once you're done with them.

Answer (score 5):

`int (*)(void*, void*)` is the comparator for C `qsort()` function. In C++ `std::sort()` the prototype to the comparator is:

```
bool cmp(const hits_object* lhs, const hits_object* rhs)
{
    return lhs->position < rhs->position;
}

std::sort(hits.begin(), hits.end(), &cmp);
```

On the other hand, you can use `std::pair` struct, which by default compares its first fields:

```
typedef std::pair<int position, unsigned long int hash> hits_object;
// ...
std::sort(hits.begin(), hits.end());
```

Comment: This `std::pair` thing wouldn't work either with a vector of pointers. `:(` Otherwise this is the best answer. `+1` from me.

Answer (score 4):

The third argument you pass to `std::sort()` must have a signature similar to, and the semantics of, `operator<()`:

```
bool is_smaller_position(const hits_object* lhs, const hits_object* rhs)
{
  return lhs->position < rhs->position;
}
```

When you store pointers in a vector, you cannot overload `operator<()`, because smaller-than is fixed for all built-in types.

---

On a sidenote: ***[Do not use `malloc()` in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/184537/in-what-cases-do-i-use-malloc-vs-new)***, use `new` instead. Also, I wonder why you are not using ***objects***, rather than pointers. Finally, if `concurrent_vector` is anything like `std::vector`, you need to ***explicitly make it expand*** to accommodate new objects. This is what your code would then look like:

```
concurrent_vector<hits_object*> hits;

for(i=0;...){
    hits_object obj;
    obj.position=i;
    obj.hash=_prevHash[tid];
    hits.push_back(obj);
}
```

Comment: "or you pass a third argument to std::sort()" Isn't that what the OP does?

Comment: I think I'll stick with passing a third argument. That overloading seems a bit non-intuitive to me! Thanks for your comment.

Comment: It's a vector of *pointers* to structs. Hence, dasblinkenlight's answer is more correct. Maybe change the `&` to `*`?

Comment: @AaronMcDaid: Ouch. I didn't see that. Fixed.

Comment: @AntonioPérez: Yeah, nice, but doesn't work for containers storing pointers.

Comment: @sbi: [Specify comparison types for associative containers of pointers](http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/programming/cplusplus/9780321545183/associative-containers/91#X2ludGVybmFsX0ZsYXNoUmVhZGVyP3htbGlkPTk3ODAzMjE1NDUxODMvODg=) and you can solve sorting for both object and pointer containers.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't look right:

```
for(i=0;...){
    hits_object *obj=(hits_object*)malloc(sizeof(hits_object));
    obj->position=i;
    obj->hash=_prevHash[tid];
    hits[i]=obj;
}
```

here you already are sorting the array based on 'i' because you set position to i as well as it becomes the index of hits!

also why using `malloc`, you should use new(/delete) instead. You could then create a simple constructor for the structure to initialize the hits_object

e.g.

```
struct hits_object
{
   int position;
   unsigned int hash;

   hits_object( int p, unsigned int h ) : position(p), hash(h) {;}
};
```

then later write instead

```
hits_object* obj = new hits_object( i, _prevHash[tid] );
```

or even

```
hits.push_back(  new hits_object( i, _prevHash[tid] ) );
```

Finally, your compare function should use the same data type as vector for its arguments

```
bool cmp( hits_object* p1, hits_object* p2 )
{
  return p1->position < p2->position;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a Lambda instead of a function to `std::sort`.

```
struct test
{
    int x;
};

std::vector<test> tests;

std::sort(tests.begin(), tests.end(),
    [](const test* a, const test* b) 
    { 
        return a->x < b->x; 
    });
```