# Sorting struct using STL:algorithm

Tags: c++

I was looking a way to sort struct using sort() function of STL:Algorithm library.
I found a couple of codes using vector to do this. for example

```
struct person {
   std::string name;
   int age;
};
bool sort_by_name( const person & lhs, const person & rhs )
{
   return lhs.name < rhs.name;
}
bool sort_by_age( const person & lhs, const person & rhs )
{
   return lhs.age < rhs.age;
}
int main() {
   std::vector<person> people;
   // fill in the vector
   std::sort( people.begin(), people.end(), sort_by_name );
   std::sort( people.begin(), people.end(), sort_by_age );
}
```

I want to know is it possible to sort it without using vector.?? If yes then how??

Comment: You can sort an array, or any other container, like `deque` or `list`.

Comment: how can you sort a struct? you can always sort a collection

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use std::sort with a vector of structures and compare function?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/328955/how-to-use-stdsort-with-a-vector-of-structures-and-compare-function)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The **[std::sort](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/sort/)** algorithm takes 3 arguments:

- Random-Access iterators to the initial position.
- Random-Access iterators to the final position and
- Sorting criteria

So as long as you have ***any type*** which can provide the initial and final iterators and you provide the sorting criteria, you can use `std::sort`on that type.
It is important though that sorting criteria has ***Strict Weak Ordering***.

Comment: I thought this still worked on normal arrays despite not actually being a Random-Access Iterator. Is this true, or are they only compatible with other things?

Comment: @chris: A pointer *is* a Random-Access Iterator. (An array name decays to a pointer to the first element of the array when passed to a function.)

Comment: @HighCommander4, oh, my bad. I haven't really gone too in-depth with iterators themselves, I just use them. Thanks for the free knowledge.

Comment: @chris: To be precise: What Standard Library has are iterator ***categories*** and ***not classes***, A category only defines abilities of iterators, the type doesn't matter. Anything that ***behaves*** like an Random Iterator ***is*** an Random Iterator.