# Can I sort C-style array (in my case of struct) using std::sort?

Tags: c++, sorting

Is it possible to sort an array of struct (I mean a C-style array, not a std::array), using std::sort or should I use qsort?

P.S. I know, I should use std::vector or std::array instead of using new and delete or to create array with `type name [size]`, but I would like to know anyway.

Comment: Are you asking for arrays of the form `int v[10];` or `int* v = new int[10];`?

Comment: Yes you can, just provide begin/end.

Comment: @Rakete1111, both

Comment: @Jarod42 so simply with `std::sort(v, v+size*sizeof(v))`?

Comment: After I answered, I found this while checking: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5897319/how-to-use-stdsort-to-sort-an-array-in-c

Comment: `v+size` does already the correct arithmetic. multiplying by `sizeof` is wrong.

Comment: @Jarod42 oooh it is true! Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use std::begin and std::end to determine the start and end points of your array, assuming you are on C++11.

So:

```
int someArray[10]
std::sort(std::begin(someArray), std::end(someArray));
```

Comment: Wow! I did not know that I could use std::begin and std::end this way!

Comment: @Nisba, for a struct you still have to provide  a comparison function object as a third parameter which this answer doesn't show.

Comment: @rex oh yes I know that ;)

Comment: @Nisba Ok, good. :) And also remember that it must ensure [strict weak ordering](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10779203/1460794). A [std::tie](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37269108/1460794) might be the easiest way for the struct members.

Comment: @rex Thanks for teaching me something new about structs!