# Heap Sorting With Vectors

Tags: c++, sorting

I have a struct:

```
struct incorrect
{
    unsigned short question;
    unsigned short answerChoice;
}
```

And a heap sort function:

```
template <typename iterator>
void heapSort(iterator begin,iterator end)
{
    make_heap(begin,end);
    sort_heap(begin,end);
}
```

And a function to merge questions of the vectors of the structure "incorrect". The problem I face is when I try to sort a vector of the structure "incorrect" using the following syntax:

```
heapSort(omitKey1.question.begin(),omitKey1.question.end());
```

I receive the error that question is not a member of incorrect. How can I fix this problem?
(I also tried removing ".question" but that didn't seem to help)

Comment: It is a vector of the structure "incorrect" or simply vector<incorrect>

Comment: @user3093536: Then it doesn't have a `question` member...

Comment: please share link to your code

Comment: unsigned short question;

<- Is this not a member of the structure called question?
I believe I forgot to mention that I pushed back "incorrect()" into the vector first

Comment: aseem, is what I just said not clear?

Comment: @user3093536: frankly speaking at first i  didn't knew answer to the question , so i thought if i have the code , i will `try` to to make some changes and make it compile .

Answer (score 1):

I think you have something like

```
vector<struct incorrect>omitKey1
```

So , use `sort(omitKey1.begin(),omitKey1.end(),compare);`

and in compare use : `return structure1.question < structure2.question`

Also , this just sorts the `vector` , not the `heap` , so i may not have answer for sorting heap .

Meanwhile look at http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/sort_heap/

@user3093536   [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/328955/how-to-use-stdsort-with-a-vector-of-structures-and-compare-function) should help .

Comment: Where would I put "return structure.question < structure.question"? And what is the point of structure1 and structure2?

Comment: This doesn't help whatsoever if I can't understand it